# Gitlab CI: jobs config should contain at least one visible job

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

i have started to build my .gitlab-ci.yml on Gitlab CI so i created it with simple stages like this

```
image: node:alpine

variables:
  PUBLIC_URL: /my-app

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

install_dependencies:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/

deploy_to_cloud:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo Deployed
```

but job failed and responded with:
Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml:

"jobs config should contain at least one visible job"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is probably some sort of BOM or other invalid characters in your yml which are not visible.
Try validating it with another editor to check that. If you found nothing, try to delete the file and recreate it again using another method.

Comment: just removed and created it again with the same code snippet and it works perfectly, Thanks

Comment: This caused me huge amount of grief, trying to figure out if there were any YML errors. Thanks for posting this solution!!! (Wish documentation in Gitlab was better on this aspect!)

Answer (score 11):

*Note:*
the answer is not specific for this case, but might be useful to mention, since I missed this [GitLab behaviour, from the official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#hide-jobs).

(if you do, please edit or comment)

#### My case

I was having a main `gitlab-ci.yaml` that `include`d definitions from a template.

*gitlab-ci-template*

```
.deploy_to_cloud:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo Deployed
```

*gitlab-ci*

```
include: repo.url/gitlab-ci-template

stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  extends: .deploy_to_cloud
```

#### The problem

After copy-pasting and merging all in a single `gitlab-ci.yml` file

*gitlab-ci*

```
stages:
  - deploy_to_cloud

.deploy_to_cloud:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo Deployed
```

I started to get a

> *jobs config should contain at least one visible job*

and to notice that no job was being created anymore; this, just by moving some code to another place.

The problem was because I forgot to rename all the stage definitions!

#### The solution

There is Gitlab-CI naming rule:

> **The stage definition name **must not** start with a leading dot; otherwise it will be hidden and no job will be created for that stage!**

Once noticed it makes total sense, given that linux files behave the same way.

Removing the initial dot from the stage definition name made Gitlab see the jobs again in my case.

*gitlab-ci*

```
stages:
  - deploy_to_cloud

deploy_to_cloud:   # notice the removed dot at the beginning
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo Deployed
```

Comment: deploy_to_cloud is a job name, not a stage name. The stage for that job is deploy

Answer (score 0):

In my case, was a space in the beginning of the file. I delete it ad works now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'd miswritten `stages` as `stage`.

```yaml
stage: # this is the problem. it should be "stages"
  - install

job-install:
  stage: install
  script:
    - npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case was just a wrong indexation issue (with the script parameter):

Before:

```
build_job:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker
script:
 - echo "Maven compile started"
 - "mvn compile"
```

After:

```
build_job:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - echo "Maven compile started"
    - "mvn compile"
```